# Which React Native app navigation option to take if I start coding today?

Tags: react-native

Navigation Experimental, Navigator, Flux-style Navigation etc. etc. There are so many theories and options out there. I know, this is a question with a very high "it depends" potential. But maybe some of you have already figured out an absolute favourite option to handle navigation for react native apps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a redux user and use https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/ . You can integrate it with redux. React-native-router-flux is also usable without Redux.

The advantage is that the Navigation API doesn't change as much as React-native's does. There is also pretty good community support.

If you start application you can use this starter kit https://github.com/infinitered/ignite. This starter kit contain redux and  React-native-router-flux. And more 
features (Battle Tested, redux persist, ...)

Comment: thx for your tip. following my own research and evaluation, this option more and more becomes my favourite too.